# Call menu on canvas problem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I have the tree of my tree outline show below:
[image]

From the picture, I have to touch at scaleCanvas for 2 second, then the wsMenu will appear at this touch point. But when menu appeared, I hope the TouchEventArgs to found wsMenu which appear on my finger but it still found scaleCanvas at lower level. I want that finger to routed again and found wsMenu which shown in the red line. If it still like this I can choose menu at the next touch only.

Best Regards, 

C.Porawat

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test this with a touch device, it works with a mouse -

Try calling `wsMenu.CaptureMouse()` after the menu has appeared.

Comment: Thanks kowd, it help me some ways but it doesn't what I want. I hope e.source will be changed. Actually, I hope it to re-RoutedEvent again in that touch so that it will changed the e.source.

Comment: It still not work. it found everytime although I didn't touch it. It should be found when my finger touch on it only. Regards, C.Porawat